# Change meta and control keys in emacs for mac keyboard

Tags: macos, emacs

There are several things I'd like to do:

- leave the left control key as is
- map the left command key so it's a meta key
- map the right command key so it's a meta key
- map the right up arrow so it's a control key

I know the three map commands need to be of the form:

```
(define-key KEYMAP KEY DEF)
```

Also I know my `.emacs` file located in my home directory. However, I'm not sure how to define these three values or if I have the right idea.

One other thing, I installed emacs 24, but I noticed that mac OSX seems to also come with emacs 22. I'd like both to function the same. Is there a way to make sure the key mappings match? Or even better replace emacs 22 with 24 in the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Emacs has a numbers of mac specific settings, including something similar what you ask for. They are included in the group 'Ns'.

use: `M-x customize-group RET ns RET`

I'm not really sure if left and right is treated separately. So maybe in addition you might want to install [keyremap4macbook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/). This can do some remapping - even on application specific basis.

Personally I found it usefull to use the `fn` key as wildcard e.g. I remap `left alt` to `fn` and tell emacs to treat `fn` as `meta`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was able to change the command key into the meta key. I wasn't able to find the option for mapping the up arrow, I also wasn't able to get to the menu from the terminal on my mac as it seems like neither alt nor command are recognized as meta from the terminal.

Comment: I believe Terminal.app has another option whether alt is sent as Meta or used to create special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Never figured this out. My solution was to switch out keyboards so now I have my command keys mapped to meta and my alt keys mapped to control.